# SQL query to check if a name begins and ends with a vowel

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to query the list of `CITY` names from the table `STATION(id, city, longitude, latitude)` which have vowels as both their first and last characters. The result cannot contain duplicates.

For this is I wrote a query like `WHERE NAME LIKE 'a%'` that had 25 conditions, each vowel for every other vowel, which is quite unwieldy. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Ideas:  regular expression or `left()`/`right()`.

Comment: Even though the problem is interesting per se, you should have changed table and field names to make it less explicitly about the question "Weather Observation Station 8" from http://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-8/problem, instead of just copying the question.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  city RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Comment: 100%, regex is e definitely the way to go! Note, this syntax is MySQL.

Comment: what if there are just 2 characters in string ?? let's say 'ae'

Comment: SQL0104N An unexpected token "RLIKE" was found following "m station where 

    city". Expected tokens may include: "LIKE". SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: @KarenGoh that looks like a [tag:sql-server] error. The question was about [tag:mysql]

Answer (score 48):

in **Microsoft SQL server** you can achieve this from below query:

```
SELECT distinct City FROM STATION WHERE City LIKE '[AEIOU]%[AEIOU]'
```

**Or**

```
SELECT distinct City FROM STATION WHERE City LIKE '[A,E,I,O,U]%[A,E,I,O,U]'
```

**Update --Added Oracle Query**

> --Way 1 --It should work in all Oracle versions

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(CITY), '^[aeiou]') and  REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(CITY), '[aeiou]$');
```

> --Way 2 --it may fail in some versions of Oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(CITY), '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]');
```

> --Way 3 --it may fail in some versions of Oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]', 'i');
```

Comment: Is there any shorthand query like this for Oracle SQL?

Comment: I like this solution. I don't find the REGEXP necessary here. This seems the most simple/elegant

Comment: In Microsoft SQL server you can achieve this from below query:

select distinct city from station where city like '[aeiou]%';

Answer (score 17):

Use a regular expression.

```
WHERE name REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

`^` and `$` anchor the match to the beginning and end of the value.

In my test, this won't use an index on the `name` column, so it will need to perform a full scan, as would

```
WHERE name LIKE 'a%a' OR name LIKE 'a%e' ...
```

I think to make it use an index you'd need to use a union of queries that each test the first letter.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name LIKE 'a%' AND name REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name LIKE 'e%' AND name REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name LIKE 'i%' AND name REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name LIKE 'o%' AND name REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name LIKE 'u%' AND name REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
```

Comment: Just pure curiousity.. is the engine clever enough to use indexes (instead of a full table scan)?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can check with `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I just checked on one of my tables, it didn't use an index.

Comment: @Barmar What does .* mean. Can you please explain

Comment: `.` matches any character, `*` matches any number (including 0) of the preceding pattern. So `.*` matches anything. Go to www.regular-expression.info to read a tutorial on regexp.

Answer (score 14):

You can try one simple solution for MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city REGEXP "^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$";
```

Comment: SQL0104N An unexpected token "REGEXP" was found following "M station WHERE 

    city". Expected tokens may include: "IN". SQLSTATE=42601

Answer (score 12):

You may try this

```
    select city
    from station where SUBSTRING(city,1,1) in ('A','E','I','O','U') and 
    SUBSTRING(city,-1,1) in ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Comment: Great way!
One question, does it check for both capital AIEOU and small aieou or only the capital ones?

Answer (score 7):

You could substring the first and last character and compare it with IN keyword,

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(NAME,1,1) IN (a,e,i,o,u) AND SUBSTRING(NAME,-1) IN (a,e,i,o,u)
```

Comment: Your query may need single quotes for the characters inside the IN parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT distinct CITY 
FROM STATION 
where (CITY LIKE 'a%' 
    OR CITY LIKE 'e%' 
    OR CITY LIKE 'i%' 
    OR CITY LIKE 'o%'
    OR CITY LIKE 'u%'
) AND (CITY LIKE '%a' 
    OR CITY LIKE '%e'
    OR CITY LIKE '%i'
    OR CITY LIKE '%o'
    OR CITY LIKE '%u'
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following regular expression ***and invert the result***:

```
^[^aeiou]|[^aeiou]$
```

This works even if the input consists of a single character. It should work across different regex engines.

***[MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c6daf8d20f140e9c40488db0c20ca260)***

```sql
SELECT city
FROM (
    SELECT 'xx' AS city UNION
    SELECT 'ax'         UNION
    SELECT 'xa'         UNION
    SELECT 'aa'         UNION
    SELECT 'x'          UNION
    SELECT 'a'
) AS station
WHERE NOT city REGEXP '^[^aeiou]|[^aeiou]$'
```

***PostgreSQL***

```sql
WHERE NOT city ~ '^[^aeiou]|[^aeiou]$'
```

***[Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c93740e752fbc7d209763a0303258407)***

```sql
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^[^aeiou]|[^aeiou]$')`
```

***SQL Server***

No regular expression support. Use `LIKE` clause with square brackets:

```sql
WHERE city LIKE '[aeiou]%' AND city LIKE '%[aeiou]'
```

Answer (score 4):

The below query will do for Orale DB:

```
select distinct(city) from station where upper(substr(city, 1,1)) in ('A','E','I','O','U') and upper(substr(city, length(city),1)) in ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

**I hope this will help**

```
select distinct city from station where lower(substring(city,1,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u') and lower(substring(city,length(city),length(city))) in ('a','e','i','o','u') ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this as I tried and it worked for me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION  
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou]' AND CITY REGEXP '[aeiou]$';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
select distinct city 
from station 
where city like '%[aeuio]'and city like '[aeuio]%' Order by City;
```

Answer (score 2):

The below one worked for me in MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE SUBSTR(CITY,1,1) IN ('A','E','I','O','U') AND SUBSTR(CITY,-1,1) in ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Comment: SQL0138N A numeric argument of a built-in string function is out of range. 

    SQLSTATE=22011

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY From STATION WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(CITY,1,1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

this will work in my sql

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM station 
WHERE SUBSTR(lower(CITY),1,1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') AND SUBSTR(lower(CITY),-1) IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL, this could be the way:

```
select distinct city from station 
where
right(city,1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o','u') and left(city,1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o','u')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for beginning with vowel

Oracle:

```
select distinct *field* from *tablename* where SUBSTR(*sort field*,1,1) IN('A','E','I','O','U') Order by *Sort Field*;
```

Answer (score 1):

For MS access or MYSQL server

```
SELECT city FROM station
WHERE City LIKE '[aeiou]%'and City LIKE '%[aeiou]';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As I write this comment, someone is probably already editing your post. Next time you'll be answering a question, consider encapsulating code into the code block.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do a hard code like this, where you are checking each and every case possible, it's easy to understand for beginners

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY LIKE 'A%A' OR CITY LIKE 'E%E' OR CITY LIKE 'I%I' OR CITY LIKE 'O%O' OR
CITY LIKE 'U%U' OR CITY LIKE 'A%E' OR CITY LIKE 'A%I' OR CITY LIKE 'A%O' OR 
CITY LIKE 'A%U' OR CITY LIKE 'E%A' OR CITY LIKE 'E%I' OR CITY LIKE 'E%O' OR 
CITY LIKE 'E%U' OR CITY LIKE 'I%A' OR CITY LIKE 'I%E' OR CITY LIKE 'I%O' OR 
CITY LIKE 'I%U' OR CITY LIKE 'O%A' OR CITY LIKE 'O%E' OR CITY LIKE 'O%I' OR 
CITY LIKE 'O%U' OR CITY LIKE 'U%A' OR CITY LIKE 'U%E' OR CITY LIKE 'U%I' OR 
CITY LIKE 'U%O'
```

Comment: FOR MS SQL --> in the where clause you can also add `CITY LIKE '[a,e,i,o,u]%[a,e,i,o,u]'` to save you from typing all possible combinations. add to the square brackets as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LEFT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [`RIGHT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) functions. `Left(CITY,1)` will get the first character of `CITY` from left. `Right(CITY,1)` will get the first character of `CITY` from right (last character of `CITY`).

`DISTINCT` is used to remove duplicates. To make the comparison case-insensitive, we will use the [`LOWER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE LOWER(LEFT(CITY,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') AND
      LOWER(RIGHT(CITY,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Answer (score 1):

***Try this below code,***

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM   STATIOn
WHERE  city RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*.[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(city) from STATION 
where lower(substr(city, -1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u') 
      and lower(substr(city, 1,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sequal server management studio (SSMS)[image: the images shows that we are getting what exactly you have asked]

SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY  LIKE '[a,e,i,o,u]%[a,e,i,o,u]';

Comment: that just messed up. but it works thanks

Comment: Messed up means? reply with your query please.

Answer (score 1):

**Following all queries work. :)**

```
select distinct(t.city) from station t where lower(substr(t.city,1,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u') and lower(substr(t.city,length(t.city),1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u');

select t.city from station t where lower(RIGHT(t.city,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u') and lower(substr(t.city,1,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u'); 

select t.city from station t where lower(RIGHT(t.city,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u') and lower(left(t.city,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the statements below work in Microsoft SQL SERVER

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    city
FROM
    station
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(lower(CITY), 1, 1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    AND SUBSTRING(lower(CITY), LEN(CITY), 1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

SELECT DISTINCT
    City
FROM
    Station
WHERE
    City LIKE '[A, E, O, U, I]%[A, E, O, U, I]'
ORDER BY
    City;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  city RLIKE '^[^aeiouAEIOU]'OR city RLIKE'[^aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Comment: Apologies! the above query results the cities that DO NOT have vowels as first or last character

Comment: Please try the following:
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM station 
WHERE city RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]' OR city RLIKE'[aeiouAEIOU]$'

Comment: Try posting answers to new questions. This was asked in 2014 and already has an accepted answer. The new questions need your attention more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select distinct city from station where city REGEXP '^[aeiou]' and city REGEXP '[aeiou]$';
```

Answer (score 0):

For oracle :

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$','i') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY  LIKE '[a,e,i,o,u]%[a,e,i,o,u]';
```

Comment: How is this any different from already existing Answers to this post? For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40073750/5411817.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me using simple left, right functions in MS SQL

```sql
select city from station where left(city,1) in ('a','e','i','o','u') and right(city,1) in ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on oracle:

```
select distinct COLUMN_NAME
from TABLE_NAME
where 
    --convert first character and check for vowel
    lower(substr(COLUMN_NAME, 1, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    and
    --convert last character and check for vowel
    lower(substr(COLUMN_NAME, -1, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
order by COLUMN_NAME asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in MYSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[a,e,i,o,u]' AND 
CITY REGEXP '[a,e,i,o,u]$';
```

Answer (score 0):

Itried this and works :
`SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city REGEXP "^[aeiou].*"`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, try this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE 'A%' OR CITY LIKE 'E%' OR CITY LIKE 'I%' OR CITY LIKE 'O%' OR CITY LIKE 'U%';
```

Comment: First, the question is tagged "mysql" so I don't know if a solution for SQL Server is appropriate. Second, the question states: _which have vowels as both their first and last characters_ Looks to me that your query only tests whether the city name starts with a vowel. It doesn't test whether the name also ends in a vowel. Nevertheless, an incorrect answer is considered to be a valid answer. Lastly, learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from station where city like '%[aeiou]';
```

**MS SQL**: change % sign to front of vowels this will select cities ending in with vowels.

Answer (score -1):

*FOR Query the list of **CITY** names from **STATION** which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates.*

**SELECT MY SQL AS the Preferred Engine**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOUaeiou]' AND CITY REGEXP '[AEIOUaeiou]$' ;
```

Very simple answer.