# Get a list strings not starting with, or ending on a vowel

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to print all the cities that do not start with a vowel, and they also must not end on a vowel.
I am aware that there is a lot of tutorial about how to do it when it must not start with a specific letter. But I am not able to find it, expressing several letters.

This is what I tried:

```
select distinct city
from station
where city not like '%[aeiou]%';
```

So if I say

```
where city not like '%a'
```

I will get the cities that do not end with the letter `a`.

Doing:

```
where city not like 'a%'
```

I will get the cities that do not start with the letter `a`

So my attempt with: `where city not like '%[aeiou]%';` is to combine the two. Id does not throw an error, it does give me a list, but just not the correct result. Actually the list is so big, that I don't know what the expression I wrote above gives me. I tried several other attempts, but this is probably the most qualified one.

How can I get a list of all cities that do not start with, or end with a vowel?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: You'll find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627613/sql-query-to-check-if-a-name-begins-and-ends-with-a-vowel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use the [`SUBSTRING()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function:

```
WHERE LOWER(SUBSTRING(city, 1, 1)) NOT IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
AND LOWER(SUBSTRING(city, -1, 1)) NOT IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

I also use the `LOWER()` function here, so that you don't have to repeat the same for upper case letters.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you would use regular expression.  This pattern:

```
where city not like '%[aeiou]%';
```

will return all cities, because no city -- to my knowledge -- has a name with the sequence of characters `'[aeiou]'` in it.  The above would do something more meaningful in SQL Server or Sybase, where those patterns are supported by `like`.

The regular expression looks like:

```
where city regexp '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*[^aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
    declare @Station table (city varchar(100))
    insert into @station select 'Houston'
    insert into @station select 'Astoria'
    insert into @station select 'enigma'


    select distinct 
         city
    from
         @Station
    where
         city not like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

Comment: No, it's not. LIKE does not work with those square brackets. Also note, that the question is tagged with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct(city) from station WHERE (CITY not LIKE 'A%' and CITY not LIKE 'E%' and CITY not LIKE 'I%' and CITY not LIKE 'O%' and CITY not LIKE 'U%') or (CITY not LIKE '%A' and CITY not LIKE '%E' and CITY not LIKE '%I' and CITY not LIKE '%O' and CITY not LIKE '%U');