# MYSQL REGEXP not searching simultaneosly two conditions

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

I'm trying to find all city names NOT starting AND not ending with vowels but the REGEXP isn't searching properly the two conditions, what am I doing wrong?

It doesn't work when I try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOU].*[AEIOU]$'
```

Because it brings city names like 'Arlinton'

Comment: you have mentioned city names should `NOT` start with .... but you are missing `NOT` in your `where`  query.

Comment: Why use a regex here? This will do: `SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE 
 LOWER(LEFT(city,1)) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u') AND LOWER(RIGHT(city,1)) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u')`

Comment: By the way, your question is a pure duplicate, even with same table name and column name, see this [identic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017952/get-a-list-strings-not-starting-with-or-ending-on-a-vowel)

Comment: @JonasMetzler and that questions points to an even older identical question [SQL query to check if a name begins and ends with a vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627613/sql-query-to-check-if-a-name-begins-and-ends-with-a-vowel)

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '^[AEIOUaeiou]' 
AND CITY NOT REGEXP '[AEIOUaeiou]$';
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE NOT (CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOUaeiou]' OR CITY REGEXP '[AEIOUaeiou]$');
```

you can play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02eaa7/2