# How to retrieve rows that begin and end with vowels?

Tags: mysql

Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627613/sql-query-to-check-if-a-name-begins-and-ends-with-a-vowel

Comment: `Your result cannot contain duplicates.` is this your homework?

Comment: try with `REGEXP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`LEFT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [`RIGHT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) functions. `Left(CITY,1)` will get the first character of `CITY` from left. `Right(CITY,1)` will get the first character of `CITY` from right (last character of `CITY`).

`DISTINCT` is used to remove duplicates. To make the comparison case-insensitive, we will use the [`LOWER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE LOWER(LEFT(CITY,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') AND
      LOWER(RIGHT(CITY,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `REGEXP`

**Explanation:** The below query will select all the DISTINCT rows where cities starts with **a vowel** as first characters, followed by any other characters **zero or more times** and finally also contains **a vowel** characters at end.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```