# Could someone help me clean this up? (Beginner, SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, string, substring, where-clause

I'm doing exercises (SQL beginner practice) on hackerrank.com, which I'm sure many of you are familiar with.

This is the question:

Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

My answer was the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(city)
FROM station
WHERE city NOT LIKE 'A%'
    AND city NOT LIKE 'E%'
    AND city NOT LIKE 'I%'
    AND city NOT LIKE 'O%'
    AND city NOT LIKE 'U%'
    AND city NOT LIKE '%a'
    AND city NOT LIKE '%e'
    AND city NOT LIKE '%i'
    AND city NOT LIKE '%o'
    AND city NOT LIKE '%u'
```

I know this is a ridiculous way to go about it- can you guys offer suggestions on how to make this shorter? I'm just not knowledgable enough in SQL at the moment to make it more succinct. If you could show a couple ways to go about it, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, oracle, ...? String functions are quite database-specific.

Comment: Actually, this SQL query isn't that bad.  In Oracle or SQL Server, this will probably perform close to the best query, depending on the size of the [station] table.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`! Remove those redundant parentheses and simply do `SELECT DISTINCT city
    FROM station...` to make code clearer.

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? Not leet enough?

Comment: With MySQL consider `RLIKE`.

Comment: thanks jarlh. And Salman, I just felt that there had to be a much shorter way to go about it that doesn't involve copy pasting that same line 10 times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query to check if a name begins and ends with a vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627613/sql-query-to-check-if-a-name-begins-and-ends-with-a-vowel)

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you can use [the `REGEXP` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
select distinct city
from station
where city not regexp '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

If your column has a case-sensitive collation, then you can lower the value before comparison:

```
where lower(city) not regexp '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

Or, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use  [`regexp_like()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) and set the match argument to `'i'` to make the search case-insensitive:

```
where not regexp_like(city, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$', 'i')
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may help

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE city NOT LIKE '[AEIOUaeiou]%[AEIOUaeiou]'
```

However, this answer is not %100 correct without knowing exact RDBMS system which you are using

Comment: This is SQL Server specific.

Answer (score 1):

If regex is an option then check that the city does not match the following pattern:

```
^[aeiou]|[aeiou]$
```

This pattern matches `ax`, `xa`, `aa` and `a` i.e. "city starts with or ends with a vowel". When you invert the result it becomes "city does not start with and does not end with a vowel". See De Morgan's law.

MySQL implementation:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city, NOT city REGEXP '^[aeiou]|[aeiou]$' AS result
FROM (
    SELECT 'xx' AS city UNION
    SELECT 'ax'         UNION
    SELECT 'xa'         UNION
    SELECT 'aa'         UNION
    SELECT 'x'          UNION
    SELECT 'a'
) AS station

-- returns 1 for xx and x, 0 for all others
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dervis - This might be a bit faster.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(city)
FROM station
WHERE UPPER(city) NOT LIKE '[AEIOU]%[AEIOU]'
```

Comment: With this, you need function index in order to work it faster. So this is not index friendly

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu Sure, but the number of cities is bound to be relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

Query the list of `CITY` names from `STATION` that either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

THIS IS FOR MS SQL USERS

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[^aeiou]%' OR CITY LIKE '%[^aeiou]';
```