# Can we use LIKE and IN together in mysql,If not then why?

Tags: mysql

I was doing a Hackerrank question by using both LIKE and IN but I was not getting any output. I am beginner in mysql.

> Query the list of CITY names starting with vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, or u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates.
>
> Input format:
> The STATION table is described as follows:
>
> where city is VARCHAR2(21)

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM STATION
WHERE city IN ('a%','e%','i%','o%','u%');
```

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627613/sql-query-to-check-if-a-name-begins-and-ends-with-a-vowel

Comment: The question needs you to test only the most first letter. Why you test the whole value?

Comment: We can, but you haven't used `LIKE` at all in your query,